# Ubuntu 16.04 - keep an x86_64 application running

Tags: 16.04, server, systemd, services

I have a very (seemingly) simple question, of how to keep an x86_64 application "alive" on an Ubuntu server.  Initially and through great effort (I am very inexperienced with Ubuntu/Linux), I was able to have it boot on startup, however the application seems to "die" every once in a while anyway.

I attempted to make the application into a service, like so:

```
[Unit]
Description=runs the mmo
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/root/mmo/MMO.x86_64
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and uploaded it via ftp to `/etc/systemd/system` on my server and set the permissions to 777,  however the file I uploaded (the icon) looks different from the other `.service` files so I think I did something wrong.

[image: screenshot of file on server]

It looks like a text document, while the other ones look like like shortcuts to folders, even though I named mine `.service` also.

What am I doing wrong?

```
root@server1:~# systemctl status mmo
* mmo.service - runs the mmo
   Loaded: error (Reason: Invalid argument)
   Active: failed (Result: signal) since Thu 2018-01-04 02:48:53 UTC; 2 days ago
 Main PID: 757 (code=killed, signal=KILL)

Jan 06 13:44:41 server1.nwg.website systemd[1]: mmo.service: Service has Restart
Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomple
lines 1-7/7 (END)
* mmo.service - runs the mmo
   Loaded: error (Reason: Invalid argument)
   Active: failed (Result: signal) since Thu 2018-01-04 02:48:53 UTC; 2 days ago
 Main PID: 757 (code=killed, signal=KILL)
```

**EDIT / progress :** Now able to start the service ( more info in the long comments below), however when I try to add `Restart=on-failure` it gives the error where it complains that the service has a restart - I tried changing it to `simple` but that didn't help - what do I do?

Comment: I'd recommend to start the service as a seperate user instead of root. Apart from that you could use a simple bash-script to check if the process is running and then restart if necessary. You could start this script with bg in the background or use a cronjob to check every minute if its still there.

Answer (score 1):

Your steps were correct so far. I would recommend to set the permissions to 644 as the service file does not need to be executable.
You also have to run `systemctl daemon-reload` to pick up the new `.service` file. If you do changes to this file, you have to run this command to pick up the changes as well.

To make your service restart, you could add the `Restart` option in the `[Service]` section.

```
...
[Service]
...
Restart=on-failure
...
```

You also could add the option as follows, to control the interval between the restart attemps. Default seems to be `100ms`.

```
RestartSec=
```

For further details refer to `man systemd.service`.

Comment: thank you Thomas for your  quick reply! the issue is that the service doesn't appear when typing service --status-all,  ( even after rebooting or systemctl daemon-reload ) - in the above screenshot, you can see the file looks different for some reason, not sure if it is because I'm using windows - I tried editing and uploading it on OSX but same thing

Comment: You have to use `systemctl [status|start|stop|reload...]` to control and configure the service. `service` is obsolete with Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Okay, I tried to run it but it says "invalid argument" :  root@server1:~# systemctl start mmo.service

Failed to start mmo.service: Unit mmo.service is not loaded properly: Invalid ar                                             gument.

server1.nwg.website systemd[1]: mmo.service: Service has Restart
Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomple
lines 1-7/7 (END)...skipping...
* mmo.service - runs the mmo
   Loaded: error (Reason: Invalid argument)
   Active: failed (Result: signal) since Thu 2018-01-04 02:48:53 UTC; 2 days ago

Comment: ( I updated the .service and added the  Restart=on-failure code - I updated the original post to reflect this)

Comment: What is the output of `systemctl status mmo` and `journalctl -u mmo`?

Comment: Okay, we are getting somewhere now, it said: Service has Restart= setting other than no, which isn't allowed for Type=oneshot services. - I removed the Restart option ( I also tried changing the service to "simple" but that didn't help - which one should I choose?) Anyhow I removed that, and now the error is mmo.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /root/mmo/MMO.x86_64: Permission denied
- I changed the permission on MMO.x86_6 to 777 but it still gives the same error :(

Comment: Okay, Seems that setting the permissions in the ftp client wasn't enough, setting chmod +x  MMO.x86_64 did the trick and the service starts - the question now is about the issue where it complains about the Restart " mmo.service: Service has Restart"